# Best zoom walk around lens for Canon 40D

Tags: lens, equipment-recommendation, canon-40d

I am about to take a trip of a lifetime to the Galapagos. I recently tried the L series 70-200 cannon but it is so heavy I hate it. I would like to find a zoom much lighter that give quality photos and has stabilization. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try the f/2.8 or the f/4? The f/4 is about half the weight of the f/2.8.

Comment: See http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/24381/galapagos-vacation-what-photo-gear-should-i-take

Comment: 1.Price 2.Weight 3.Quality - You can have two, but not three.

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, the 70-200 is not what I'd call a "walk around" lens  It can be cumbersome and get heavy after a while especially if you have the f/2.8 version. As someone mentioned before, the f/4 version is a lot lighter.

For a regular all-rounder have you considered the following:-

**EF-S 17-55mm f/2.8 IS USM**

**EF 24-105mm f/4 L IS USM**

**EF 24-70mm f/2.8 L USM**

The EF-S 17-55mm really is one heck of an upgrade from the standard kit lens, and being that your 40D has a crop sensor - it will accept the EF-S lenses.  It has a constant f/2.8 aperture through the whole zoom range, really fast USM, and the image stabiliser you were after...  I had this lens for over a year and was consistently impressed by the image quality.  It also has the UD and low-dispersion glass elements of its bigger brothers in the L series, so the quality is high.

The EF 24-105mm is a chunky option but not overly heavy.  It is a full L grade lens with all the build quality that you would expect from an L.  It has a constant f/4 aperture through the zoom range, which is usually more than adequate for most work, especially daytime things.  Although it has a smaller aperture than the 17-55 or 24-70 it still has the image stabiliser built in to give you a couple of stops extra leaway.

The EF 24-70mm does not have IS, but few users miss it.  Another chunky peice of glass with a constant f/2.8 aperture ensures good shutter speed even in low light and good DoF.  It can be quite heavy after a while, but it is a seriously good bit of L series glass.  Canon have, this year, released a version II of it, though as I understand this has been subject to delays and is still in short supply; but what that means is that the old version of this lens (still fantastic) should be readily available and perhaps at a better price too (though it is still expensive!).

These are the lenses I would say would be good for a "walk around" lens.  The 70-200 you mention would be a telephoto zoom great for if you can't get close to your subject, but you won't so easily be able to do landscape work with it (but it is possible -- I once did a landscape at 400mm!!).  I hope those options help you out...

Comment: The EF 24-70mm f/2.8L lens is not sharp enough. I would not buy it again

Comment: @Andrew - For years it has appeared in the kits of the majority of portrait photographers. Yes L primes are sharper, but the trade-offs for most working professionals have not been enough to keep them from buying it and using it often. The mkII version is obviously a huge step up in this regard, but I wouldn't write off the MkI as an option either.

Comment: @Andrew - For years it has appeared in the kits of the majority of portrait photographers. Yes L primes are sharper, but the trade-offs for most working professionals have not been enough to keep them from buying it and using it often. The mkII version is obviously a huge step up in this regard, but I wouldn't write off the MkI as an option either.